# What functor can make categories equivalent

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

I’m reading Jacobson’s book “Basic Algebra II”,and confused by the proof of the following theorem for long long time.

> Let $F$ be a functor from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{D}$.Then there exists a functor $G:\mathcal{D}\to \mathcal{C}$ such that $(F,G)$ is an equivalence iff $F$ is faithful, full and essentially surjective.

And my confusion is about the proof of the necessity. The author says that

> $GF\cong 1_{\mathcal{C}}$ implies that the map $f\mapsto GF(f)$ of $Hom(A,B)$ onto $Hom(GF(A),GF(B))$ is bijective.
> Similarly,$g\mapsto FG(g)$ is bijective.

The claim above is what I can accept. However, the following one borthered me for hours

> the surjectivity of $g\mapsto FG(g)$ implies the surjectivity of $f\mapsto F(f)$.

I don’t know how can “imply”.

we know that $F$ is full iff for any given $A,B\in ob\mathcal{C}$, for any $g\in Hom_{\mathcal{D}}(F(A),F(B))$, there exists $f\in Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(A,B)$ such that $F(f)=g$. It seems that we want to use the surjectivity of $FG$. However, I don’t know how to ensure the appropriate domain of $FG$. It seems that we must have $A’,B’\in ob\mathcal{C}$ such that $G(A’)=A$,$G(B’)=B$. And then we can say that there must exist some $f’\in Hom(A’,B’)$ such that $FG(f’)=g$.

I thought this problem for hours and asked my classmate for help. Unfortunately,they also don’t know why.

I do feel like I'm going crazy, and I really wish someone would answer me in details.

Thank you very much

Comment: If a composition $f\circ g$ of functions is surjective, then so must be $f$: let $z$ be any element of the codomain of $f$, then there's an $x$ such that $f(g(x))=z$ so $g(x)$ is a good feed for $f$ to obtain $z$.

Comment: @Berci However, I don’t know how to ensure there exists $A’,B’\in ob\mathcal{D}$ such that $G(A’)=A,G(B’)=B$ for any given $A,B\in ob\mathcal{C}$. Or we cannot use your conclusion.

Comment: @Berci I have rewritten the problem and supplemented some more details of my confusion. I do hope you can give me more suggestions.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We want to prove that $F$ is full and faithful, which is exactly the statement
$$\forall g\in\hom_{\mathcal D}(FA,\,FB)\,\exists! f\in\hom_{\mathcal C}(A,B):\,Ff=g$$
that you seem to understand already.
Then we have $Gg\in \hom_{\mathcal C}(GFA,\,GFB)$ which is in bijection with $\hom_{\mathcal C}(A,B)$ via the full and faithful functor $GF$.

Nevertheless, since it's an equivalence, $A'=FA$ and $B'=FB$ will be good candidates for what you seem to be missing.
Well, we can't guarantee mere equality $GA'=A$ and $GB'=B$, instead we only have (natural) isomorphisms $GFA\cong A$ and $GFB\cong B$, and composing by these given isomorphisms or their inverses readily proves the one-to-one correspondence
$$\hom_{\mathcal C}(A,B)\ \cong\ \hom_{\mathcal C}(GFA,\,GFB)\,.$$